# how to add desktop widgets in linux

Tags: gnome, desktop-environment

I was wondering if there is any way to add desktop widgets in gnome like those in the photo. The photo uses rainmeter for it. Rainmeter is not available for linux. I want them to be fully customizable.

i am using Zorin OS 16 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

ram:4gb

gnome: 3.38.4

[image: What i want]
**What i want**

[image: my current desktop]
**My current desktop**

Answer (score 1):

This is probably conky, here's how you can install and configure it: https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-install-and-configure-conky/

It's not a widget, it's a full-featured application.